# Getting values from xelement

Tags: xml, linq, entity-framework

I'm learing linq. I have a Xelement like below

```
<Customer>
 <Orders>
   <param id="13" title="Book1" />
   <param id="15" title="Book2" />
 </Orders>
<Customer/>
```

How to get the value of id as a comma delimited string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
XElement xe = XElement.Parse(xmlString);

var ids = 
    String
    .Join
    (
        ",",
        xe
        .Elements("Orders")
        .Elements("param")
        .Select(x=>x.Attribute("id").Value)
        .ToArray()
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var ids = XElement.Load(xmlString)
    .Descendants("param")
    .Select(e => e.Attribute("id").Value);
var result = String.Join(",", ids);
```