# Get value inside XElement

Tags: c#, xml, linq, parsing

I've been trying forever using Descendants, Elements and attributes to retrieve data from an XML file that I'm writing to save metadata. I can't at the moment and it's blocking my work. When I was using Linq to XML, I was yielding no value whatsoever and I couldn't under why happening.

Quick look into the xml file

```
    <ImageMetadata>
        <ColorHistogram>
            <Bin value="45861"/>
            <Bin value="31989"/>
        </ColorHistogram/>
        <FaceLocations>
            <FacePosition Y="379" X="205"/>
            <FacePosition Y="366" X="372"/>
        </FaceLocations>
    </ImageMetadata>
```

I've tried different solutions. At first, I only had an XElement called BinValue instead of the tag Bin with the attribute value which lead to this code:

```
  //Yielding no results

  from elements in doc.Descendants()
  let element = elements.Element("BinValue")
  select (long)element;
```

Then after getting mad at LINQ to XML, I changed the structure a bit of my document to have a tag and an attribute. But this have no effect whatsoever.

```
var bins = XElement.Load(dbMetadata)
                .Descendants("Bin")
                .Select(e => e.Attribute("value").Value);
// which gives me : System.ArgumentException: 'Illegal characters in path.'
```

[Getting values from xelement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19240256/getting-values-from-xelement)

My use case has you could have gather from the xml structure is the following: creating metadata of an image file. That portion looks pretty solid with OpenCV and that's not my issue. Maybe in order to get more feedback on my issue, it'd be relevant to add the code I was using to build my XML document.

The portion that computes data on an image was done using F#. The part that creates the xml document was done using C#. Because of that, I'm going to create two gists to share my code. Please, remember to add the Emgu OpenCV nugget package in your solutions.

1. [Image Analyzer - F#](https://gist.github.com/Kavignon/404e948db14823436ad46c55e4f16f0b)
2. [XMLDocumentParser - C#](https://gist.github.com/Kavignon/0e4a73f17f82a2022ba191c6e3220968)

**Use any two local jpg files in order to run the F# code that will generate the metadata !

**If possible, I'd like a way to retrieve the data using LINQ to XML. For both ColorHistogram and FaceLocations

**UPDATE1**

I was asked in the comments to show the state of the xml file when my problems occurred. You can find it below:

[Metadata file](https://gist.github.com/Kavignon/c06a650e7f2175f2dbd014ad1891de02)

Comment: What was the value of `dbMetadata` when the error occurred?

Comment: @har07 The state of dbMetadata is inside the Metadata file. I've made an update to my post

Comment: It looks like you've only shown part of the XML file. It would be helpful if you'd provide a [mcve]. This could easily be due to a default XML namespace in the root for example. (With the file you've linked to, maybe not... but basically there's too much clutter in this question - a single short console app would make this much simpler to fix.)

Comment: @KevinAvignon if `dbMetadata` contains the actual XML, then you should've used `Parse()` instead of `Load()`. The latter expects string containing path to the XML file.

Comment: @JonSkeet reading it again I can see some issues in my query. I'll make an update to my question by removing the partial xml and linking directly the file from the start to remove any ambiguities

Comment: @Har07 ooh I hadn't paid attention to the difference between the two methods. That could explain why I was battling my know to xml queries for so long sadly! Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication49
{

    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            var results = doc.Descendants("ImageMetadata").Select(x => new
            {
                colorHistograms = x.Descendants("ColorHistogram").Select(y => new
                {
                    bin = y.Elements("Bin").Select(z => new
                    {
                        value = (int)z.Attribute("value")
                    }).ToList()
                }).FirstOrDefault(),
                faceLocations = x.Descendants("FaceLocations").Select(y => new
                {
                    facePosition = y.Elements("FacePosition").Select(z => new
                    {
                        X = (int)z.Attribute("X"),
                        Y = (int)z.Attribute("Y")
                    }).ToList()
                }).FirstOrDefault()

            }).FirstOrDefault();


        }
    }


}
```